# Gehört das Nomen "Kantor" zu der Gruppe der N-Deklination?

Tags: noun

Ich kann nicht verstehen, ob das Nomen "*Kantor*" zu der Gruppe der N-Deklination gehört oder nicht. Kann jemand mir bitte helfen? Ich danke im Voraus!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deklination von »Kantor«:

> Nom: der Kantor, die Kantoren
>   Gen: des Kantors, der Kantoren
>   Dat: dem Kantor, den Kantoren
>   Akk: den Kantor, die Kantoren

Schema der N-Deklination (z.B. »Name«, »Student«, »Christ«, »Pädagoge«):

> Nom: der -, die -(e)n
>   Gen: des -(e)**n**(s), der -(e)n
>   Dat: dem -(e)**n**, den -(e)n
>   Akk: den -(e)**n**, die -(e)n

Alle Nomen, die nach der N-Deklination dekliniert werden, erhalten im **Singular** im Genitiv, Dativ und Akkusativ ein abschließendes »*n*«, dem gegebenenfalls noch ein »*e*« vorangestellt wird. Im Genitiv ist auch noch ein weiteres »*s*« möglich (der Name - des Namens).

Nichts davon trifft auf den Kantor zu (der Kantor, des Kantors). Daher gehört dieses Wort nicht zur N-Deklination.

Die Deklinationsgruppe, zu der Kantor gehört, heißt W3. Das ist eine Mischgruppe, bei der im Singular stark (mit -(e)s im Genitiv) und im Plural schwach dekliniert wird. Zu dieser Gruppe gehören nicht nur Kantor, Doktor, Inspektor, Autor usw., sondern auch Auge, Ohr, Schmerz, Bett und viele andere.

Answer (score 2):

Hubert Schölnasts Antwort ist natürlich völlig richtig, wie auch ein kurzer [Blick in den Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kantor) zeigt. Das ist auch alles, was man unbedingt wissen muss.

Allerdings scheint mir bei *Kantor* wie bei den meisten lateinischstämmigen Wörtern auf -or (z.B. *Autor, Diktator*) daneben auch die n-Deklination nicht völlig falsch zu sein. Man hört sie gelegentlich, und sie wirkt auf mich nicht wirklich falsch, sondern eher wie eine exzentrische Variante. Dazu noch Folgendes:

- Googles n-Gramm-Viewer kennt diese Variante für *Kantor* überhaupt nicht, bei *Autor* ist sie dagegen nur sehr selten. Der Unterschied dürfte aber einfach nur darin begründet sein, dass das Wort *Kantor* an sich schon sehr viel seltener ist.
- Wahrscheinlich handelt es sich in vielen Fällen um eine Hyperkorrektur. *Herr* fällt beispielsweise definitiv unter n-Deklination, wird aber umgangssprachlich sehr vereinzelt wie *Autor* und *Kantor* dekliniert, was dann falsch und sehr ungebildet klingt ("das Auto des Herrs; dem Herren mal aufs Dach steigen"). Der Gedanke liegt nahe, dass manche Leute bei *Kantor* Angst haben, denselben Fehler zu begehen.
- Wer erst mal unsicher ist, findet in vielen Wörterbüchern den Deklinationshinweis "-s, -en". Das wird sicher häufig dahin gehend missverstanden, dass man beim Genitiv die Wahl zwischen *-s* und *-en* hätte. In Wirklichkeit gibt *-en* allerdings den Plural an.
- Die Fugenlaute, die im Deutschen bei der Zusammensetzung von Substantiven auftreten, bilden morphologisch gesehen ein System ähnlich einem fünften Fall. Dieses System scheint allerdings nicht systematisch erfasst worden zu sein, ist definitiv aus Wörterbüchern nur indirekt zu erschließen (wenn dort auch eine Zusammensetzung mit dem betreffenden Substantiv vorne zu finden ist), und unterliegt neben gelegentlicher Abhängigkeit vom Folgewort (deshalb linguistisch gesehen kein Fall!) wohl auch deutlich stärkeren regionalen und sonstigen Schwankungen als die Fälle. (Ich vermute, es liegt einfach daran, dass dieses System nicht reglementiert ist und sich deshalb natürlicher entwickelt.)
  Diese Fugenlaute sind meist (nicht immer!) vom Genitiv oder vom Plural abgeleitet. Da vielen Leute nicht bewusst ist, dass es nicht immer der Genitiv ist, kommt es leicht zu dem Fehlschluss , wenn es *Autorenlesung* und *Kantorenvermächtnis* heißt, müssten die Genitive auch *des Autoren, des Kantoren* sein.
- Warum auch immer die Variante sich hält - sie scheint mir jedenfalls in gehobener Sprache häufiger zu sein als in ungepflegter Umgangssprache. Für einen Romantitel würde ich sie unter Umständen vielleicht sogar vorziehen. Beispiel: *Das Vermächtnis des Kantoren*.
- In Gedichten hat man aus meiner Sicht vollends die Wahl. In diesem Kontext scheint mir die n-Deklination genauso wenig falsch zu sein wie ein unreiner Reim. "Vor dem Auge des Kantoren // bleibt keine Note ungeschoren." (Die n-Deklination ist hier das geringste Problem!)
- Das Phänomen ist überhaupt nicht neu. Mit Google Books findet man leicht alle möglichen Belege für "des Autoren" oder "dem Autoren" im 19. Jahrhundert, auch wenn es schon damals eher selten war. (Leicht erkennbar daran, dass die Mehrheit der Suchtreffer sich durch Trennungen von zusammengesetzten Wörtern ergibt.) Mir scheint es eine Häufung von süddeutschen, österreichischen und schweizerischen Treffern zu geben. Evt. war die n-Deklinition von Wörtern auf *-or* in der [oberdeutschen Schreibsprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberdeutsche_Schreibsprache) ja sogar Standard?
- In Büchern des (späten) 18. Jahrhunderts scheint die n-Deklination dieser Wörter noch mit der heutigen Standarddeklination vergleichbar häufig gewesen zu sein. Das wurde wohl erst danach standardisiert.

Weil es so schön ist, zum Abschluss noch ein Beispiel aus einer Buchkritik von 1840:

> Aber leider hat er nicht bedacht, daß diese erbärmliche Zuschaustellung von Citaten, die er zuweilen aus alten und sehr respectabeln Autoren entlehnt, nicht mehr an der Mode ist, und daß man sie heutzutage, um sie nach ihrem wahren Werthe abzuschätzen, — « marqueterie littéraire » — nennt, deren einziger Zweck ist, den Lesern durch **die Gelehrsamkeit des Autoren** zu imponiren, und eine peinliche Erzählung und einen farblosen Styl mit schimmerndem Sande zu überstreuen.

Comment: Sorry, die N-Deklination für lateinischstämmige Wörtern auf -or für richtig zu halten halte ich für nicht richtig. Die N-Deklination für z.B. »Kantor« würde bedeuten: »Das ist das Buch des *Kantoren*.« (statt *... des Kantors*), »Dieses Buch gehört dem *Kantoren*.« (statt *... dem Kantor*) und »Ich sehe den *Kantoren*.« (statt *... den Kantor*). Noch auffälliger ist das beim viel häufiger gebrauchten Wort »Doktor«: »Das ist das Buch des *Doktoren*.« (statt *... des Doktors*), »Dieses Buch gehört dem *Doktoren*.« (statt *... dem Doktor*) und »Ich sehe den *Doktoren*.« (statt *... den Doktor*).

Comment: Sicher, es ist heute definitiv nicht richtig. Da es aber vor etwas über 200 Jahren weit verbreitet war - auf einem Sprachstand, mit dem wir heute durchaus noch einigermaßen vertraut sind -, ist es auch nicht wirklich falsch sondern lediglich etwas archaisch. Das ist ein wichtiger Unterschied, weil Menschen, die voll phat angesagt daherlabern, eher ungebildet rüberkommen, wohingegen es eher als Zeichen von Kultur gilt, sich verstaubter Wendungen zu befleißigen.